# Javascript: Accessing the values from JSON Object Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I receive a JSON string returned from a remote Webservice. Something like this:

```
[{
    "id": "001",
    "link": "<a href=\"https://www.google.com\">Google</a>"
}, {
    "id": "002",
    "link": "<a href=\"https://www.yahoo.com\">Yahoo!</a>"
}]
```

But then when i try to parse it in my Javascript, i have problem parsing it. I tried:

```
var response_string = '[{"id":"001","link":"<a href=\"https://www.google.com\">Google</a>"},{"id":"002","link":"<a href=\"https://www.yahoo.com\">Yahoo!</a>"}]';
console.log("Output (1) --> ", response_string);

response_string = JSON.stringify(response_string);
console.log("Output (2) --> ", response_string);

var response_object = JSON.parse(response_string);
console.log("Output (3) --> ", response_object);

console.log("Value: " + response_object[0].id);
console.log("Value: " + response_object[0]['id']);
```

Then the outputs are like:

```
Output (1) -->  [{"id":"001","link":"<a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a>"},{"id":"002","link":"<a href="https://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo!</a>"}]

Output (2) -->  "[{\"id\":\"001\",\"link\":\"<a href=\"https://www.google.com\">Google</a>\"},{\"id\":\"002\",\"link\":\"<a href=\"https://www.yahoo.com\">Yahoo!</a>\"}]"

Output (3) -->  [{"id":"001","link":"<a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a>"},{"id":"002","link":"<a href="https://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo!</a>"}]

Value: undefined

Value: undefined
```

How do i access the values inside this object please?

Comment: Before output 2 you stringify you json string. Before outupt 3 you parse that stringified json string and get back the json string again. Remove you `JSON.stringify` and everthing will work fine.

Comment: So why do you stringify a string? What is the point for that?

Comment: You are getting a string of JSON then _stringifying_ it thus making it a double encoded JSON and then parsing it once.

Comment: @t.niese: not quite: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token h in JSON at position 30(…)`

Comment: @zerkms: Remove that stringify. Try to `parse` the OP's string. ___It does not work___. I'm not sure why, though.

Comment: @Cerbrus it would work if you took the raw JSON string. There is difference between a string literal and string received from somewhere. You cannot simply copy it and expect it to work.

Comment: @zerkms: I'm telling you, ___it doesn't___. Try it yourself!

Comment: @Cerbrus you're not following me - OP copied the string for demonstration but you cannot do that. If you take the raw JSON string it would be fine.

Comment: @t.niese they provided valid JSON in the beginning of the question actually.

Comment: @Cerbrus it doesn't work because it's invalid. here is what the string contains `"{"link":"<a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a>"}"` -> notice the quotes around `href`

Comment: `JSON.parse('[{"id": "001","link": "<a href=\\"https://www.google.com\\">Google</a>"}, {"id": "002","link": "<a href=\\"https://www.yahoo.com\\">Yahoo!</a>"}]');` --- here, see that their JSON is perfectly valid. But expecting that JSON string can be copied as a string literal is the mistake they've made.

Comment: @KrisRoofe not relevant

Answer (score 3):

You cannot simply copy-paste the raw response as-is and use it as a string literal, since the string literals have their own syntactic rules.

One of those - is using escape sequences, is where you've made a mistake.

If you want to use it in place you must escape every backslash manually, like

```js
var response_object = JSON.parse('[{"id": "001","link": "<a href=\\"https://www.google.com\\">Google</a>"}, {"id": "002","link": "<a href=\\"https://www.yahoo.com\\">Yahoo!</a>"}]');
// --------------------------------------------------------------^^-----------------------^^----------------------------------------------^^----------------------^^
console.log("Value: " + response_object[0].id);
```

For the code that retrieves the JSON string from a remote server you don't need to make any alterations and simply `JSON.parse()` would parse it just fine.

So assuming `response_string` contains the whole response from a remote server with a mentioned JSON string (without any additional processing), then this:

```
var response_object = JSON.parse(response_string);
console.log("Output (3) --> ", response_object);
```

code would work.

Comment: I know the issue if from the source, with "double quotes". But as i mentioned, it is from remote webservice. I cannot correct it. How do i do (please) since i receiving as it is?

Comment: @夏期劇場 when retrieved from a remote server it would work just fine. (see the last sentence in the answer)

Comment: @夏期劇場: What this answer is saying: Remove this line: `response_string = JSON.stringify(response_string);`, and then your code works.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the **webservice** sends ***invalid*** JSON.

```
{"JSON": "This is "not" valid JSON" }
```

The *quotation marks* in any JSON have to be **escaped**:

```
{"JSON": "This is \"valid\" JSON" }
```

Any Unicode character except **"** or **\** will be treated by parser as it was.

The **"** represents termination, while **\** is treated differently depending on which character comes after it. For example `\n`, here the letter **n** comes after **\** it will be treated as newline character. Below picture taken from [json.org](https://json.org) describes it better:

[image]

So, you should report this bug to the webservice providers. It has to be fixed.

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain what is wrong with this answer?

Answer (score -2):

Parse json like this

```
var res = JSON.parse('[{"id": "001","link": "<a href=\\"https://www.google.com\\">Google</a>"}, {"id": "002","link": "<a href=\\"https://www.yahoo.com\\">Yahoo!</a>"}]');
console.log(res);
console.log(res[0].id);
```

Comment: I know the issue if from the source, with "double quotes". But as i mentioned, it is from remote webservice. I cannot correct it. How do i do (please) since i receiving as it is?